# Zero Percent Brightness Bug?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

Device: TorqueXT, Android 4.4.2

When I set the brightness to zero, and I turn off the screen and turn it back on, the screen is brighter even thought it still says it's on zero brightness (and when I raise the brightness and bring it back to zero it becomes darker than when it turned on). This only happens with the zero percent brightness.

I have completely formatted the device to see if that fixed it, but no success. Also, after formatting, I've installed a third-party app to control brightness, and it still does not maintain the zero percent brightness.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @GiantTree, thanks for the input. I hope it is software however so that it might get fixed for next update. My solution has been using a blue-light filter that can "dim" the screen as well (I'm using Twilight, and pretty happy with it)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue  some users, including me, are experiencing. There is nothing you can do about it, as it seems to come from the hardware level (the screen) not maintaining the brightness level.